# Need help writing a PostgreSQL trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgis

I have two tables representing two different types of imagery.  I am using PostGIS to represent the boundaries of those images.  Here is a simplified example of those tables:

```
CREATE TABLE img_format_a (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    file_path VARCHAR(1000),
    boundary GEOGRAPHY(POLYGON, 4326)
);

CREATE TABLE img_format_p (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    file_path VARCHAR(1000),
    boundary GEOGRAPHY(POLYGON, 4326)
);
```

I also have a cross reference table, which I want to contain all the IDs of the images that overlap each other.  Whenever an image of type "A" gets inserted into the database, I want to check to see whether it overlaps any of the existing imagery of type "P" (and vice versa) and insert corresponding entries into the `img_a_img_p` cross reference table.  This table should represent a many-to-many relationship.

My first instinct is to write a trigger to manage this`img_a_img_p` table.  I've never created a trigger before, so let me know if this is a silly thing to do, but it seems to make sense to me.  So I create the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_a_p_cross_reference
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF boundary
    ON img_format_p FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_p_cross_reference();
```

The part where I am getting stuck is with writing the trigger function.  My code is in Java and I see that there are tools like PL/pgSQL, but I'm not sure if that's what I should use or if I even need one of those special add-ons.

Essentially all I need the trigger to do is update the cross reference table each time a new image gets inserted into either `img_format_a` or `img_format_p`.  When a new image is inserted, I would like to use a PostGIS function like `ST_Intersects` to determine whether the new image overlaps with any of the images in the other table.  For each image pair where `ST_INTERSECTS` returns true, I would like to insert a new entry into `img_a_img_p` with the ID's of both images.  Can someone help me figure out how to write this trigger function?  Here is some pseudocode:

```
SELECT * FROM img_format_p P
    WHERE ST_Intersects(A.boundary, P.boundary);

for each match in selection {
    INSERT INTO img_a_img_p VALUES (A.id, P.id);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap the usual `INSERT ... SELECT` idiom in a PL/pgSQL function sort of like this:

```
create function check_p_cross_reference() returns trigger as
$$
begin
    insert into img_a_img_p (img_a_id, img_p_id)
    select a.id, p.id
    from img_format_a, img_format_p
    where p.id = NEW.id
      and ST_Intersects(a.boundary, p.boundary);
    return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Triggers have two extra variables, [`NEW` and `OLD`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> **NEW**
>   Data type RECORD; variable holding the new database row for INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is NULL in statement-level triggers and for DELETE operations.
>
> **OLD**
>   Data type RECORD; variable holding the old database row for UPDATE/DELETE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is NULL in statement-level triggers and for INSERT operations.

So you can use `NEW.id` to access the new `img_format_p` value that's going in. You (currently) [can't use the plain SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/triggers.html) language for triggers:

> It is not currently possible to write a trigger function in the plain SQL function language.

but PL/pgSQL is pretty close. This would make sense as an AFTER INSERT trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_a_p_cross_reference
AFTER INSERT
ON img_format_p FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_p_cross_reference();
```

Deletes could be handled with a [foreign key on `img_a_img_p` and a cascading delete](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK). You could use your trigger for UPDATEs as well:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_a_p_cross_reference
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF boundary
ON img_format_p FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_p_cross_reference();
```

but you'd probably want to clear out the old entries before inserting the new ones with something like:

```
delete from img_a_img_p where img_p_id = NEW.id;
```

before the `INSERT...SELECT` statement.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such an awesome and detailed answer.  I appreciate it!

Comment: When I run your trigger function, I get this error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "insert"` `LINE 3:     insert into  img_a_img_p (img_a_id, img_p_id)`.  Do you know why I would get this?  PL/pgSQL should be installed by default for spatial databases, right?  I'm having trouble understanding this error.

Comment: @Steph: That's because I missed a "begin" in the procedure (see the new third line). Sorry, I just wrote that off the top of my head without testing it.

Comment: Ah, that fixed it.  Sorry, I should have been able to figure that one out.  :-P